# Can anyone explain the grammar behind the "sentence ending" とでも?

Tags: grammar

Is it an abbreviation of a longer phrase? Or is it just kind of like the American street slang, "And what..?" As in, "You think you're hot? And what..?"

But in this case perhaps it is almost like asking if the listener had any "buts" or objections to the statement.

> そんな[怒]{いか}りに[妾]{わらわ}が[怯]{ひる}むとでも？
>   And you think that anger would make me flinch?

> 「それが[実証]{じっしょう}できるとでも？」
>   `You're going to verify THAT?'

> あなたに言われないと分からないとでも？
>   Like I need you to tell me that.

> 「ほかになりようがあるとでも？」と[女王]{じょおう}さま。
>   'What would you have it?' said the Queen. (from Alice in Wonderland)

> 同性愛者ですが何か？それが[犯罪]{はんざい}だとでも？
>   So what if I am gay? Is it a crime?

Source:

[http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=とでも？](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%EF%BC%9F)

Comment: Agh, damn. I didn't see this and answered in the other question... Mhhh.

Comment: @ Hyperworm, I'll accept that as an answer if you provide a source or are a native speaker/super fluent. I am just a little wary as none of the translations provided on alc used "or something," but perhaps that is just a matter of translators preference.

Comment: Japanese dictionaries don't include entries for `とでも`, but it's relatively common.  I think that's evidence that lexicographers see it as the simple combination of `と` and `でも`.  If it meant something different, I think it'd be considered common enough to get an entry in at least *some* dictionaries.  (Of course, I'm not a native speaker, nor am I "super fluent"!)

Comment: @yadokari If you decide to accept Hyperworm's explanation in the answer on the other question, could you please mark this as a duplicate ("already has an answer on another question")?  (I'm not trying to make you decide whether to accept it, of course.  If you don't feel it's been answered, then do as you see fit :-) )

Answer (score 3):

In these cases, '思っているのか？' or '言いたいのか？' is omitted.

そんな[怒]{いか}りに[妾]{わらわ}が[怯]{ひる}むとでも**思っているのか**？ or
そんな怒りに妾が怯むとでも**言いたいのか**？

あなたに言われないと分からないとでも**思っているのか**？  or
あなたに言われないと分からないとでも**言いたいのか**？

「ほかになりようがあるとでも**思っているのですか**？」と女王さま。 or
「ほかになりようがあるとでも**言いたいのですか**？」と女王さま。

同性愛者ですが何か？それが[犯罪]{はんざい}だとでも**思っているのですか**？ or
同性愛者ですが何か？それが犯罪だとでも**言いたいのですか**？

～と思う、～と言う is basic form.
でも（副助詞） adds some emphasis.